# How to make a small $\varhexagon$ in latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, math-operators

I would like to have a command that shrinks down the size of `$\varhexagon$` from the wasysym package in latex to a very small size.

In principle, `$\tiny \varhexagon$` does what I want, but apparently the command "`tiny`" is not allowed in math mode.

Is there a way to circumvent this?-Note that `\scriptscriptstyle` does not seem to give the same size as `\tiny`.

In short, I want a command that does the same as `$A_{\tiny \varhexagon}$` but does not use the illegal command `\tiny`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX it is not a duplicate, since none of the suggestions gives precisely the same size as \tiny.

Comment: @J.Doe scale to `\tiny` or to `\large` is the same concept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, `\tiny` is a text mode command and thus is not allowed in math mode.

What you may be looking for is

```
\newcommand\tinyvarhexagon{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.5}{$\varhexagon$}}}}
```

where `\scalebox` is a macro provided by the `graphic` package and `\vcenter` and `\hbox` are TeX "primitive". `\tiny` corresponds to a linear reduction in font size of 50%; hence the `0.5` scaling factor. With this definition, the tiny hexagon is centered vertically on the math axis. If you would rather have the resized symbol placed on the baseline, just omit the `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` "wrapper".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym} % for "\varhexagon" macro
\usepackage{graphicx}% for "\scalebox" macro
\newcommand\tinyvarhexagon{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.5}{$\varhexagon$}}}}
   % ("\vcenter" and "\hbox" are TeX primitives)

\begin{document}
$a\varhexagon a$ $a\tinyvarhexagon a$ $a\scalebox{0.5}{$\varhexagon$} a$ 

$A_{\varhexagon}$ $A_{\tinyvarhexagon}$ $A_{\scalebox{0.5}{$\varhexagon$}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: well, unfortunately it does not give the same size as tiny

Comment: @J.Doe - Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can load the font with a different scaling factor:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wasysym} % just for comparison

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{wasysmall}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wasysmall}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> s*[0.75] wasy5
  <5.5-6.5> s*[0.75] wasy6
  <6.5-7.5> s*[0.75] wasy7
  <7.5-8.5> s*[0.75] wasy8
  <8.5-9.5> s*[0.75] wasy9
  <9.5-> s*[0.75] wasy10
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wasysmall}{b}{n}{
  <-5.5> s*[0.75] wasyb5
  <5.5-6.5> s*[0.75] wasyb6
  <6.5-7.5> s*[0.75] wasyb7
  <7.5-8.5> s*[0.75] wasyb8
  <8.5-9.5> s*[0.75] wasyb9
  <9.5-> s*[0.75] wasyb10
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wasysmall}{bx}{n}{ <-> sub * wasysmall/b/n}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{wasysmall}{U}{wasysmall}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{wasysmall}{bold}{U}{wasysmall}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\smallhexagon}{\mathord}{wasysmall}{57}

\begin{document}

{\tiny\varhexagon} $\scriptstyle\smallhexagon$ $A_{\smallhexagon}$

\end{document}
```

Note that loading `wasysym` is not required, I did just for the comparison.

[image]

You can avoid wasting a symbol font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{wasysmall}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wasysmall}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> s*[0.75] wasy5
  <5.5-6.5> s*[0.75] wasy6
  <6.5-7.5> s*[0.75] wasy7
  <7.5-8.5> s*[0.75] wasy8
  <8.5-9.5> s*[0.75] wasy9
  <9.5-> s*[0.75] wasy10
}{}

\newcommand{\smallhexagon}{\text{\usefont{U}{wasysmall}{m}{n}\symbol{57}}}

\begin{document}

$A_{\smallhexagon}$

\end{document}
```

If you just need the symbol to change size in subscripts, you can do in a different way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mhexagon}{\mathord}{wasy}{57}

\begin{document}

$A_{\varhexagon}$ (wrong)

$A_{\mhexagon}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `amsmath` package also provides the `\text` command which allows text mode commands inside math mode without warnings (see also the [answer by @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480438/) above).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}
A{\tiny\varhexagon}

$A_{\text{\tiny\varhexagon}}$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, this approach works for both smaller text sizes as well as smaller math sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym,scalerel,lmodern}
\newcommand\xvarhexagon{\scaleto{\varhexagon}{1.4\LMex}}
\begin{document}
$\varhexagon x\xvarhexagon
\scriptstyle x\xvarhexagon
\scriptscriptstyle x\xvarhexagon$

\small$\varhexagon x\xvarhexagon
\scriptstyle x\xvarhexagon
\scriptscriptstyle x\xvarhexagon$

\footnotesize$\varhexagon x\xvarhexagon
\scriptstyle x\xvarhexagon
\scriptscriptstyle x\xvarhexagon$

\scriptsize$\varhexagon x\xvarhexagon
\scriptstyle x\xvarhexagon
\scriptscriptstyle x\xvarhexagon$

\tiny$\varhexagon x\xvarhexagon
\scriptstyle x\xvarhexagon
\scriptscriptstyle x\xvarhexagon$

\normalsize$x_{\xvarhexagon} =3\xvarhexagon y$
\end{document}
```

[image]